# How to generate a dummy variable after NAs in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I'm trying to generate a dummy variable with the following rule,

```
For DV in Data:    
    set: Flag "1" for all NA in DV
    set: Flag "0" otherwise
```

A **sample data set** is given below,

```
year    country DV
1990    Bahamas 2
1991    Bahamas NA
1992    Bahamas NA
1993    Bahamas 0
1994    Bahamas 1
1995    Bahamas 2
1996    Bahamas NA
1997    Bahamas 2
1998    Bahamas NA
1999    Bahamas 2
2000    Bahamas NA
2001    Bahamas 1
2002    Bahamas NA
2003    Bahamas 1
2004    Bahamas NA
2005    Bahamas 2
2006    Bahamas NA
2007    Bahamas 0
2008    Bahamas 1
2009    Bahamas 2
2010    Bahamas NA
2011    Bahamas 2
```

From the **rule** mentioned, it is clear that the Flags are to be set as given below,

```
year    country DV  Flag
1990    Bahamas 2   0
1991    Bahamas NA  0
1992    Bahamas NA  0
1993    Bahamas 0   1
1994    Bahamas 1   0
1995    Bahamas 2   0
1996    Bahamas NA  0
1997    Bahamas 2   1
1998    Bahamas NA  0
1999    Bahamas 2   1
2000    Bahamas NA  0
2001    Bahamas 1   1
2002    Bahamas NA  0
2003    Bahamas 1   1
2004    Bahamas NA  0
2005    Bahamas 2   1
2006    Bahamas NA  0
2007    Bahamas 0   1
2008    Bahamas 1   0
2009    Bahamas 2   0
2010    Bahamas NA  0
2011    Bahamas 2   1
```

To be clear, the **Flag** is set only on the basis of the column **DV**, regardless of what is after or before DV.

I am currently trying this:
`data$Flag <- ave(data$country, data$DV, FUN = function(x) if (max(x) == NA) 1 else 0)`

Obviously this doesn't look correct, I'm aware of this. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Easiest is `dat$flag <- as.integer(is.na(dat$DV))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `dplyr::lag` to check previous value of `DV` is `NA` and current row is `non-NA` to set `Flag` as `1` otherwise it will be `0`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Flag = ifelse(!is.na(DV) & is.na(lag(DV, default = 0)), 1, 0 ))
#    year country DV Flag
# 1  1990 Bahamas  2    0
# 2  1991 Bahamas NA    0
# 3  1992 Bahamas NA    0
# 4  1993 Bahamas  0    1
# 5  1994 Bahamas  1    0
# 6  1995 Bahamas  2    0
# 7  1996 Bahamas NA    0
# 8  1997 Bahamas  2    1
# 9  1998 Bahamas NA    0
# 10 1999 Bahamas  2    1
# 11 2000 Bahamas NA    0
# 12 2001 Bahamas  1    1
# 13 2002 Bahamas NA    0
# 14 2003 Bahamas  1    1
# 15 2004 Bahamas NA    0
# 16 2005 Bahamas  2    1
# 17 2006 Bahamas NA    0
# 18 2007 Bahamas  0    1
# 19 2008 Bahamas  1    0
# 20 2009 Bahamas  2    0
# 21 2010 Bahamas NA    0
# 22 2011 Bahamas  2    1
```

Comment: I get this error when I run the code `Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists`.

Comment: I hsould perhaps mention that I do this for more then one variable in my data: 
`df$Flag<–df %>% mutate(Flag = ifelse(!is.na(DV) & is.na(lag(DV, default = 0)), 1, 0 ))`

Comment: @Goulou You have mentioned 2 things. 1:- Code is not working for you. 2:- You want to do it for more than 1 variable. For `1st` can you confirm you are trying on data.frame. For 2nd, if you tell me number of columns and criteria how to apply this rule then I can help. Do you want to generate`Flag1` , `Flag2` etc for more than 1 column?

Comment: I solved it. It was a silly mistake from my side. I have another question out, somewhat similar. Thansk for this suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
data$X <- 0
data$X[which(is.na(data$DV)) + 1] <- !is.na(data$DV[which(is.na(data$DV)) + 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the difference of the logical vector produced by `is.na()`, and equate it to -1.  This will give you the positions of the change from NA to non-NA.

```
cbind(df, Flag = c(0, diff(is.na(df$DV)) == -1))
#    year country DV Flag
# 1  1990 Bahamas  2    0
# 2  1991 Bahamas NA    0
# 3  1992 Bahamas NA    0
# 4  1993 Bahamas  0    1
# 5  1994 Bahamas  1    0
# 6  1995 Bahamas  2    0
# 7  1996 Bahamas NA    0
# 8  1997 Bahamas  2    1
# 9  1998 Bahamas NA    0
# 10 1999 Bahamas  2    1
# 11 2000 Bahamas NA    0
# 12 2001 Bahamas  1    1
# 13 2002 Bahamas NA    0
# 14 2003 Bahamas  1    1
# 15 2004 Bahamas NA    0
# 16 2005 Bahamas  2    1
# 17 2006 Bahamas NA    0
# 18 2007 Bahamas  0    1
# 19 2008 Bahamas  1    0
# 20 2009 Bahamas  2    0
# 21 2010 Bahamas NA    0
# 22 2011 Bahamas  2    1
```

Comment: Or you could load packages for no reason and write twice the code.